# Error: break statement not within loop or switch

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I wrote this part of code and a series of error are being shown. The above mentioned error being the first. What is wrong in the code?

```
void direction(char ch)
{

switch(ch)
case 'w': if(dirn!=3){dirn=1;}
          break;

case 'a': if(dirn!=2){dirn=4;}
          break;

case 's': if(dirn!=1){dirn=3;}
          break;

case 'd': if(dirn!=4){dirn=2;}
          break;
```

Comment: Please complete your code

Comment: Just a word of advice.If you have only one line of code to be executed as part of if statement then avoid those braces. `if(dirn!=3){dirn=1;}` should actually be written as `if(dirn!=3)dirn=1;`. Those braces unnecessarily clutter your code. If you have more than one statement to execute as part of if statement then of course those braces are necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to omit the opening and closing braces for a switch statement only when you have only one case in your switch block as shown below:

```
void direction(char ch)
{
    switch(ch)
    case 'w': if(dirn!=3){dirn=1;}
}
```

But, if you have got multiple cases to deal with like in your case then you must enclose them inside a pair of opening and closing braces to create a code block for the switch statement as shown below:

```
void direction(char ch)
{

switch(ch)
{//opening brace for starting of statement block
    case 'w': if(dirn!=3){dirn=1;}
          break;

    case 'a': if(dirn!=2){dirn=4;}
          break;

    case 's': if(dirn!=1){dirn=3;}
          break;

case 'd': if(dirn!=4){dirn=2;}
          break;
}//closing brace for closing of statement block
```

So you will have to either remove all the cases but one OR add the pair of braces to create statement block. In all other cases your code won't compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

switch statement requires braces block, where all labels including default one should be:

```
switch(ch)
{
case 'w': if(dirn!=3) dirn=1;
          break;

case 'a': if(dirn!=2) dirn=4;
          break;

case 's': if(dirn!=1) dirn=3;
          break;

case 'd': if(dirn!=4) dirn=2;
          break;
default:
          break;
}
```

The statement after switch must be a *compound statement* to contain case, default and break. Break got a special meaning here, different from loops. If brace was omitted only next line after switch is part of its statement.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten the switch braces :

```
void direction(char ch)
{

    switch(ch)
    {
        case 'w': if(dirn!=3){dirn=1;}
            break;

        case 'a': if(dirn!=2){dirn=4;}
            break;

        case 's': if(dirn!=1){dirn=3;}
            break;

        case 'd': if(dirn!=4){dirn=2;}
            break;
    }
}
```